# How to print a PDF document via Bluetooth in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, ios-bluetooth

I want to print a PDF document via bluetooth, is there any possibility. I looked at some posts in SO, it says not possible but those posts are few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to print pdf documents via bluetooth.

Zebra printers are available for iOS.
https://www.zebra.com/us/en.html

Comment: can you please post the code how to print the PDF doc via Bluetooth in iOS App, i am not looking for the printer now.